# ¿Es problema de compatibilidad?

Tags: jquery

Buen día estoy empezando a trabajar con un calendario donde al hacer clic en una fecha debe abrir una ventana "modal" esto esta en una pagina JSP pero no lo hace se queda así entonces pase el código a un archivo HTML con los mismos .css y js, funciona de manera correcta

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../estilos/sic.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../estilos/calendario/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../estilos/calendario/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../estilos/calendario/bootstrap-year-calendar.min.css" type="text/css" />



  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="../../../jsp/menu/stmenu.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="../../../js/calendario/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="../../../js/calendario/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="../../../js/calendario/bootstrap-year-calendar.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="../../../js/calendario/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


</head>

<div id="calendar"></div>
<div class="modal modal-fade" id="event-moda">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">
          Event
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input name="event-index" type="hidden">
        <form class="form-horizontal">

          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
  Habilitar
  </button>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
  Des-Habilitar
  </button>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="min-date" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Dates</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
              <div class="input-group input-daterange" data-provide="datepicker">
                <input name="event-start-date" class="form-control" value="2012-04-05" type="text">
                <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
                <input name="event-end-date" class="form-control" value="2012-04-19" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
  Cancel
  </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-event">
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Y cual es el error? , podrías hacer un snippet funcional acá en la página para ver que podrías estar haciendo mal y así puedan ayudarte.

Comment: No realiza nada en JSP y ¿Donde puedo ver los pasos para hacer el snippet funcional?

Comment: ve a la parte donde editas tu respuesta y aparece un icono con este signo `<>`, ese signo abrirá un super modal para agregar tanto html como javascript y css , solo agrega código y las librerías que usaras(ojo que tienen que ser cdn).

Comment: Supongo que el archivo JSP esta dentro de un proyecto de eclipse o netbeans, revisa que el archivo JSP este cargando correctamente los recursos( JS, img, CSS)  una manera sencilla es cuando lanzes tu pagina JSP es dar click derecho en el navegador en codigo fuente y revsiar si los recursos estan siendo cargados ya que al momento que des click al enlace que carga el CSS o JS te tiene que mostrar el recurso en una nueva ventana de tu navegador.

Comment: Realice el proceso y efectivamente muestra todos los archivos JS, img y CSS, gracias por comentar.